# Aspectj not working on simple example

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I think i am missing something basic, i can't get aspectJ to work.
(i am new to aspectj)

here is my aspect file

```
@Aspect
public class AspectAPILogger {

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void atExecution(){
        System.out.println("AspectAPILogger.atExecution------------");
    }

    @Around("atExecution()")
    public void aroundX1(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("AspectAPILogger.aroundX1------------");
    }

    @Before("execution(* *(..))")
    public void beforeX(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("AspectAPILogger.beforeX------------");
    }
}
```

my gradle.build

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/aspectj.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.aspectj:gradle-aspectj:0.1.6"
    }
}

apply plugin: "aspectj.gradle"
plugins {
    id "aspectj.gradle" version "0.1.6"
}

....

ext.versionAspectJ              = '1.8.10';

...

dependencies {
.....
    //AOP
    compile group: 'org.aspectj'                 , name: 'aspectjrt'               , version: "$versionAspectJ"
    compile group: 'org.aspectj'                 , name: 'aspectjweaver'           , version: "$versionAspectJ"
.....
}
```

some small main

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Utils.md5("---");
        Utils.timerStart();
        Utils.timerStop("Some log message   ");
    }
}
```

can you help me figure out what i am missing, i guess its something basic... i also tries this plugin 'https://github.com/NikitaKozlov/WeaverLite' but i can't get a simple aspect to work, please help...

my project is a simple gradle java project

thank you !!!

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? If it's compiling the aspects, then you need to call that task: `compileAspect`. Hook it into your toolchain with `dependsOn`.